# Counting number of times group switches in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

I want to create a new column which counts how many times an IP switches domains.

**Input:**

```
    domain      ip      timestamp              next_domain    next_next_domain
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook       N/A
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook       N/A
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook       N/A
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33    N/A            N/A
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35    N/A            N/A
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41    Google         Facebook
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46    Google         Facebook
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01    Google         Facebook
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook       Youtube
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13    Youtube        N/A
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55    N/A            N/A
```

**Output:**

```
    domain      ip      timestamp              next_domain    next_next_domain  switch_count
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook       N/A               1
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook       N/A               1
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook       N/A               1
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33    N/A            N/A               1
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35    N/A            N/A               1
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41    Google         Facebook          3
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46    Google         Facebook          3
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01    Google         Facebook          3
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook       Youtube           3
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13    Youtube        N/A               3
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55    N/A            N/A               3
```

IP 101 switches 1 time because it goes from Google -> Facebook. IP 103 switches 3 times because it goes from Youtube -> Google -> Facebook -> Youtube.

How can i do this in pandas?

Answer (score 5):

You can `groupby` "ip" and on transform a lambda that checks if consecutive domain names differ (note that we just subtract 1 since we count the first domain name as well which doesn't count towards "switch"):

```
df['switch'] = df.groupby('ip')['domain'].transform(lambda x: x.shift().ne(x).sum()-1)
```

Output:

```
      domain   ip            timestamp next_domain next_next_domain  switch
0     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:41    Facebook              NaN       1
1     Google  101  2020-04-01 23:01:59    Facebook              NaN       1
2     Google  101  2020-04-02 12:01:41    Facebook              NaN       1
3   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:33         NaN              NaN       1
4   Facebook  101  2020-04-02 13:11:35         NaN              NaN       1
5    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:01:41      Google         Facebook       3
6    Youtube  103  2020-04-21 13:11:46      Google         Facebook       3
7    Youtube  103  2020-04-22 01:01:01      Google         Facebook       3
8     Google  103  2020-04-22 02:11:23    Facebook          Youtube       3
9   Facebook  103  2020-04-23 14:11:13     Youtube              NaN       3
10   Youtube  103  2020-04-23 14:11:55         NaN              NaN       3
```

Comment: Good answer man